# Convert DSL Query To NEST Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

My DSL query is below :

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 200,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "contactId": {
                                "query": "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a",
                                "type": "phrase"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I tried to convert dsl query to NEST query.

```
var descriptor =
            new SearchDescriptor<dynamic>().From(0)
                .Size(200)
                .Query(
                    a =>
                        a.Filtered(
                            b =>
                                b.Filter(
                                    c =>
                                        c.Bool(
                                            d =>
                                                d.Must(
                                                    e =>
                                                        e.Query(
                                                            f =>
                                                                f.Match(
                                                                    g =>
                                                                        g.OnField("contactId")
                                                                            .Query(
                                                                                "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a"))))))));
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(client.Serializer.Serialize(descriptor));
```

I examined the json results with the help of SearchDescriptor. There were differences :

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 200,
"query": 
{
    "filtered": 
    {
        "filter": {
            "bool": 
            {
                "must": [
                {
                    "fquery": 
                    {
                        "query": 
                        {
                            "match": 
                            {
                                "contactId": 
                                {
                                    "query": "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you can see fquery added but i didnt fquery my Nest query. Fquery why added? First DSL query is returning result but second DSL query is not returning any result

Comment: `fquery` is used just to give a name to that query. The important bit missing from your NEST query is `"type": "phrase"`. Add that and try again.

Comment: Maybe like this: `.Query(
                                                                                "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a").Type(TextQueryType.Phrase)`.

Comment: Replace `Match(..)` with `MatchPhrase(..)` so you can change type of match query as @AndreiStefan said.

Comment: I added MatchPhrase to Nest query and converted to DSLquery. Then when i execute this dsl query it returns result but when i execute Nest query it doesnt result :(  @AndreiStefan

Comment: @kbylmz may you post your updated NEST query?

Comment: @Rob my updated code is below

Answer (score 0):

My updated code :

```
var searchResults =
            client.Search<dynamic>(u=>u.From(0)
                .Size(200)
                .Query(
                    a =>
                        a.Filtered(
                            b =>
                                b.Filter(
                                    c =>
                                        c.Bool(
                                            d =>
                                                d.Must(
                                                    e =>
                                                        e.Query(
                                                            f =>
                                                                f.MatchPhrase(
                                                                    g =>
                                                                        g.OnField("contactId")
                                                                            .Query(
                                                                                "e84aca88-7b82-43d9-8788-4cc25af0c43a")))))))));
```